# Error when using caret rfe with custom functions in rfeControl

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to perform feature selection using caret::rfe() function, using a bayesglm model.

Since this model is not implemented in the functions you can pass to rfeControl, I created it, using lmFuncs as template:

```
bayesglmFuncs <- lmFuncs

bayesglmFuncs$fit <- function (x, y, first, last, ...) 
{
    tmp <- if (is.data.frame(x)) x
    else as.data.frame(x)
    tmp$y <- y
    bayesglm(y ~ ., family=binomial(link='logit'), data = tmp)
}
```

then:

```
rfecontrol <- rfeControl(functions=bayesglmFuncs, method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 3)
model.sel <- rfe(Data[,c(2:8,10,11,13:17)], Data[,12], rfeControl = rfcontrol)
```

Unfortunately it fail with this error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "undefined columns selected"

This is the data structure (uterus.atonia is the dep. variable):

```
str(Data[,c(2:8,10,11,12,14:17)])
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ prev.pregs              : int  0 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ abortions               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ born.at.term            : int  0 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ gest.days               : int  272 273 266 273 281 273 283 254 273 289 ...
 $ delivery.type           : Factor w/ 2 levels "ps","tc urgente": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mother.age              : int  35 37 25 38 40 41 38 37 35 35 ...
 $ oxytocin                : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","si": 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ prom                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","si": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ labor.induction         : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","si": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ uterus.atonia           : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","si": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ anestesia.type.locale   : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ anestesia.type.combinata: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ anestesia.type.epidurale: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ anestesia.type.spinale  : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Could you post dataset structure?

Comment: you mean via str()?

Comment: In any manner that will (succinctly) show your data's structure.

Comment: lmFuncs should be used for continous output. Use ldaFuncs for classification - this way your modification works.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer?